# HTML form, set blank form to NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML form; I want to be able to set it so that if a field is empty, the field in the DB will actually be NULL and not just have the word NULL in the field. I thought that using this code would help, but it just puts the word NULL in the field.
PHP Code:

```
<pre>
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['oc_item'])) { 
            $oc_item = mysql_escape_string($_POST['oc_item']);
            $oc_itemdesc = (!empty($_POST['oc_itemdesc'])) ? $_POST['oc_itemdesc'] : NULL;

           $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog_dev (oc_item,oc_itemdesc)
            VALUES(''$oc_item','$oc_itemdesc')";

        mysql_query($SQL);
        if (mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo '<strong><em>Your data has been submitted</em></strong><br /><br />';
                } else {
            echo '<p>Error adding submitted info: ' . mysql_error(). '</p>';
        }
        }
        ?></pre>
```

HTML Code:

```
<pre>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Name</td>
            <td><input class="forms" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" name="oc_item" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Description</td>
            <td><input class="forms" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" name="oc_itemdesc" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit item" /></p>
        </form></pre>
```

I want the field to actually be *NULL* and not have the field contain the word NULL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP `NULL` != MySQL `NULL`. Just set the field in the database to allow null, and default to null, and don't insert that field if the input is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write NULL to a MySQL database, you really have to put NULL there **without** quotation marks.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (column, column2) VALUES ('mystring', NULL);
```

It’s always a bit effort if you want to do this manually by hand, because you would have to make if-conditions for the query.

Remember: PHP `null` != MySQL `NULL`. They both do not know each other at all.

But I am still wondering, what does that all have to do with the question name? (SELECT unless)

You could write your code like this:

```
$oc_item = mysql_escape_string($_POST['oc_item']);
$oc_itemdesc = (isset($_POST['oc_itemdesc']) && trim($_POST['oc_itemdesc']) != '') ? "'" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['oc_itemdesc']) . "'" : 'NULL';

$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog_dev (oc_item,oc_itemdesc)
        VALUES('" . $oc_item . "', " . $oc_itemdesc . ")";
# sorry for adding " . all the time, but I dislike variables within strings :D
```

But I have to admit I do not like that much either, as it moves the duty to wrap quotation marks around MySQL strings away from the SQL-query itself.

Comment: Hi,I used your code and it leaves the field blank- it doesn't mark the field as *NULL*. I checked in phpmyadmin and the NULL box is not selected when I go to edit that entry, it's just blank. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, I have totally changed the code. it’s possible I wrote something that did not work. I have not used pure SQL for a while. Try the new one, and also check if the text `now we insert NULL` is printed. Then we know that the right statement is taken.

Comment: I can try that, the only problem is, I have about 20 other fields on this form. The example I posted, I just cut them out to save space. How do I incorporate them into this code?

Comment: That’s where this method fails… But I am not sure yet, why the other method failed (Tim Withers still uses). But for working with 20 variables, you have to go with his approach (parsing string vs. NULL before).

Comment: I tested my old code and as for me it seemed to work correctly. I get `"INSERT INTO catalog_dev (oc_item,oc_itemdesc) VALUES('aaa', NULL)"` as output, which would insert NULL into the database. I guess you have gotten an empty input, because your if condition evaluated to true. So something about this must be wrong `!empty(trim($_POST['oc_itemdesc']))`. Maybe you have spaces or newlines in your input, then it’ll already say that there is an input. Try `trim` (I also added it above).

Comment: Update: I tried your updated code: $oc_itemdesc = (isset($_POST['oc_itemdesc']) && trim($_POST['oc_itemdesc']) != '') ? "'" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['oc_itemdesc']) . "'" : 'NULL';               however, when I look in phpmyadmin, the field says NULL not *NULL*. The later means the field entry is actually null, the former means that the text NULL is in the field. I want the field to actually be *NULL*.  Is that possible?

Comment: Here's the code example that contains your code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47777972/add.zip

Comment: You still have `'$oc_itemdesc'` in your SQL statements, you have to remove the quotation marks to `$oc_itemdesc`

Comment: Hi, here's what I have now for that line:`$oc_itemdesc = (isset($_POST[oc_itemdesc]) && trim($_POST[oc_itemdesc]) != '') ? "'" . mysql_escape_string($_POST[oc_itemdesc]) . "'" : NULL;` The field is empty, which is fine, but there must be a way where it's actually *NULL*.?

Comment: Again,you’re using PHP null instead of MySQL null (which must be passed as a string without quotation marks within the string). As said, PHP null and MySQL NULL do not know each other at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you printed out $sql, you'd see that it's inserting `, 'NULL'`.

You need to modify your code so that it inserts the work "NULL" (*without* '' quotes) or, better, doesn't insert that parameter at all (eliminate the entire `, 'NULL'` part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$oc_itemdesc = (!empty($_POST['oc_itemdesc'])) ? "'".$_POST['oc_itemdesc']."'" : "NULL";

$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog_dev (oc_item,oc_itemdesc) 
    VALUES('$oc_item',$oc_itemdesc)";
```

As it stands you are adding `'NULL'` instead of `NULL` so it is adding the words instead of the value.

Side Note: I would be careful and properly escape/encode the `$_POST['oc_itemdesc']` as someone who put an apostrophe in the description would completely throw off the insert statement.  For example:  `I don't like this` would look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog_dev (oc_item,oc_itemdesc) 
    VALUES('$oc_item','I don't like this')";//MYSQL Error
```

PPS: As it stands you are inserting TWICE:

```
mysql_query($SQL);//insert 1
if (mysql_query($sql)) {//insert 2
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, and when I have an ' it gives me this error when submitting: Error adding submitted info: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'It\'s a test'',

Comment: Can you show the whole SQL-query (`var_dump($sql);`). I am sure it is some minor mistake about apostrophes. It’s easier to see in generated SQL code than in such PHP-SQL-mix.

Answer (score 0):

The function that I use for the MySQL data from the HTML forms.

```
function emptyHtmlFormToNull($arr){
   foreach($arr as $key => $val){
       if(empty($val) || strtolower($val) === 'null'){
           $arr[$key] = null;
       }
   }
   return $arr;
}
```